# Pass last_inserted id from one function to another function in the same class in codeigniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, class, mysqli

I want to pass my variable $lastid to another function in same class. how can i do it??.. i tried something but it doesn't work?

```
class ProductmModel extends CI_Model
{

  var $PRODUCTNAME='';
  var $DESCRIPTION='';
  var $CATEGORY='';
  var $SUBCAT='';
  var $IMAGE='';


public function addproductm()
{
$this->load->database();
$data = array(
"p_name" => $this->PRODUCTNAME,
"p_des" => $this->DESCRIPTION,
"cat" => $this->CATEGORY,
"subcat" => $this->SUBCAT

);
$this->db->insert('product_multi', $data);
$lastid = $this->db->insert_id();

}
```

This is the next function

```
public function addimage()
{
$last= $this->addproductm();
$this->load->database();

$data = array(
"pid" => $lastid,
"images" => $this->IMAGE

);
$this->db->insert('image', $data);
}
}
```

Comment: Try to pass id to function. `public function addimage($product_id)` and call this function where you want to pass id, here in `addproductm()` function as `$this->addimage($lastid)`

Comment: Why not extend the declaration of `$lastid` on global scope? http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call addimage function in your first function.try like this. i hope it will help.

```
public function addproductm()
{
$this->load->database();
$data = array(
"p_name" => $this->PRODUCTNAME,
"p_des" => $this->DESCRIPTION,
"cat" => $this->CATEGORY,
"subcat" => $this->SUBCAT
);
$this->db->insert('product_multi', $data);
$lastid = $this->db->insert_id();
$id=$this->addimage($lastid);
}

public function addimage($id)
{
$last= $this->addproductm();
$this->load->database();

$data = array(
"pid" => $id,
"images" => $this->IMAGE

);
$this->db->insert('image', $data);
}
}
```

Comment: hey if you are there can you help me.. when i use this code... blank rows are added to database just before the actual one...and blank rows count depends on number of imags im uploading..can u help?

Comment: but if im not using last_id thing it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have an auto-incremented id in your table

Second, return the `$this->db->insert_id()` from model after insertion

```
public function addproductm()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $data = array(
       "p_name" => $this->PRODUCTNAME,
       "p_des" => $this->DESCRIPTION,
       "cat" => $this->CATEGORY,
       "subcat" => $this->SUBCAT
    );
    $this->db->insert('product_multi', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Here you got last inserted id in the model like `$last_id = $this->db->insert('image', $data)`

Pass the `$last_id` to function

```
public function addimage()
{
   $last= $this->addproductm();
   $this->load->database();

   $data = array(
      "pid" => $lastid,
      "images" => $this->IMAGE
   );
   $last_id = $this->db->insert('image', $data);
   $this->function_name($last_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it. Suppose you have a function like

```
function getCirclePoints($center,$radius){

}
```

while calling the function from the same class

```
$this->getCirclePoints($latlng,radius));
```